# Forbidden (HTTP 403) for searching Google Scholar with rvest::session in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, google-scholar

I'm trying to webscrape Google Scholar. I got stuck on the very first step.

```r
rvest::session("https://scholar.google.com/")
```

> Warning message: In session_set_response(x, resp) : Forbidden (HTTP
> 403).

I think it has something to do with user agent or headers.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Is that all your code? When I run your code there is no warning message.

Comment: Hmm I tried on a different computer and it worked... Google seemed to have locked me out with my first pc. Maybe I did too many searches or something